# How to tell in OnDrawItem whether the combobox has a scrollbar or not?

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

1. How can I tell, in the OnDrawItem event handler for a TComboBox, whether the combobox currently has a scrollbar or not?
2. And how can I know the width of the scrollbar?

The use case is right-justified text or other graphical elements. I want them to be positioned x pixels from the right edge of the visible area. But currently, my attempts lead to good-looking results only as long as there is no scrollbar. As soon as the scrollbar appears (because of the number of items in the combobox vs. the DropDownCount), the scrollbar hides part of what I've drawn in OnDrawItem.

Answer (score -1):

I think that ClientWidth property takes into consideration presence of vertical scrollbar. But it may depend on Delphi version.
You can also try the following to check if vertical scrollbar is displayed:
`(GetWindowlong(comboBox.Handle, GWL_STYLE) and WS_VSCROLL) <> 0`

Comment: I don't think this makes sense at all, since the combo box control uses a list box control for its drop-down list, so the list isn't the same HWND.

Comment: You can get the `HWND` of the inner ListBox via the [`CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cb-getcomboboxinfo) message or [`GetComboBoxInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcomboboxinfo) function, and then query the ListBox for its scroll bar info

Comment: Thank you for your answers and comments. While user3848246's original answer wasn't quite right, it still lead me in the right direction, and you could edit it to become correct. I now realized that the Rect passed as argument to the OnDrawItem event handler already is adjusted for the presence/absence of the scrollbar. So all I have to do is rely upon Rect.Right.

Comment: Please note that the real answer to the actual question is "use Rect.Right". If you need to manually investigate the presence of scrollbars etc., chances are high that you are not following best practices and that there is a simpler, more robust way to accomplish what you try to do. (In this case, you also need to consider theme variations, DPI scaling, etc.)